# Выборочно отключить валидацию по сертификату для некоторых операций

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Есть рабочий сервис. В интерфейсе одна операция. Доступ к сервису изначально был по сертификату. В этом интерфейсе должна быть добавлена еще одна операция, но запрос к ней будет идти без подписи, в тоже время доступ в старой операции должен быть без изменений по сертификату :возможно ли такое осуществить ?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, такое осуществить нельзя. Можно, конечно, если очень постараться, отключить проверку подписи для операции (отключив ее вообще через кастомный валидатор, а потом проверив ее самостоятельно для первой операции). Но лучше так не делать - клиенту же все равно придется формировать подобие подписи, а зачем заниматься лишней работой?

Проще всего добавить вторую конечную точку, с другим интерфейсом и другой привязкой (binding), не требующей проверки подписи.

**UPD:**

У `SecurityBindingElement` есть свойства `OperationSupportingTokenParameters` и `OptionalOperationSupportingTokenParameters`. По всей видимости, с их помощью можно задать то поведение, которое вам требуется.

Но подробностей сказать не могу - ибо сам не знаю. Читайте RFC, fiddler и wireshark надолго станут вашими лучшими друзьями :) Эти свойства не задать через файл конфигурации, даже через `customBinding` - потому я про них и не знал. Для целей испытания имеет смысл создавать привязку в коде, не описывая ничего в файле конфигурации - потом же понадобится либо писать свой `Binding`, либо хотя бы свой `BindingElementExtensionElement`.

**В качестве альтернативного костыля** могу предложить создание прокси-сервера, который будет прослушивать запросы, приходящие на некоторый адрес - и направлять их на другие адреса в зависимости от `Action`. Такой прокси можно сделать прямо на WCF:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class Proxy {
    [OperationContract(Action="*", ReplyAction="*")]
    public Message Process(Message msg) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Для передачи сообщения по цепочке дальше можно воспользоваться интерфейсом IRequestChannel:

```
private static Binding binding = ...; // инициализация привязки

...

var channel = binding.CreateChannel<IRequestChannel>(выбранный_адрес);
return channel.Request(msg);
```

Из возможных проблем: несовпадение адреса получателя с реальным (решается разделением address и listenUri при настройке конечной точки - или подменой заголовков сообщения на стороне прокси, также можно вообще вырубить использование WS-Addressing).

Конечно же, прокси можно написать и на ASP.NET MVC или на WebApi - это же просто HTTP на транспортном уровне.

Comment: Если добавить второй EndPoint, то для доступа необходимо будет использовать второй адрес, а этого как раз и нужно избежать т.е. мне нужно по одному  URL сервис принимающий запросы к одной операции подписанные сертификатом, а к другой без такового. Я понимаю, что без промежуточного шлюза эту проблему не решить ?